# Real and fake face detection with faceapi.js

Tags: javascript, face-detection, face-api

Currently, I am trying to develop an application with face-api.js. The main purpose of the application is to login with our face. The application works fine but when we open my face photo from the phone and show it on the webcam, it still works. This situation impairs application security.
How can i detect a real face on a webcam? If the user shows a photo from his phone to the webcam, I want him to understand this and cancel the login process. This is a difficult issue for me and it is very difficult to explain.
I am waiting for your answers and ideas. I apologize for taking your time

Comment: This is not a simple problem to solve and is in fact probably impossible when relying on a standard camera. Apple's FaceID and other similar systems use infrared sensors and sensors that are able to detect depth in order to create a 3D construct of the face. A webcam can not do this, so your log in system will never be secure.

Comment: I am working on the same problem and would welcome an advice. I guess the landmarks could be used for that purpose. There are movements within the landmarks in a live video (no capture of a picture) which could be calculated. How could that be calculated?